# Save checkmarked row into appsettings. EDITED

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

EDIT: I got a saving and now It do not work.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:countries  forKey:@"country"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Saving.

But I think I must load the arrays from the appsettings. how?

Got this now:

```
countries = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"All",@"Austria",@"Belarus",@"Canada",@"Czech Republic",@"Denmark",@"Germany",@"Finland",@"France",@"Latvia",@"Norway",@"Russia",@"Slovakia",@"Slovenia",@"Switzerland",@"Sweden", @"USA", nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  **synchronize** mathod of **NSUserDefault**.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        int newRow = [indexPath row];
        int oldRow = (lastIndexPath != nil) ? [lastIndexPath row] : -1;

        if (newRow != oldRow)
        {
            UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
                                        indexPath];
            newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

            UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: 
                                        lastIndexPath]; 
            oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            lastIndexPath = indexPath;
        }
        NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        //Suppose you have used **myArrayUsedInTableView**   Array to construct TableView 
        ..................................................................................
        ............./*Do changes here in myArrayUsedInTableView  as per your requirement*/
        ....................................................................................
        //Now store your array myArrayUsedInTableView in NSUserDefault
        [defaults setObject:myArrayUsedInTableView  forKey:@"StoredArray"];
        [defaults synchronize]; 
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for response. I did you write and it do not work. I suppose I have to read arrays from the defaults? And how to read the current?